# How to unzip all zip files to similarly named directories

Tags: bash, find, unzip

I want to unzip all zip files in a directory, but I don't know how the contents were zipped (with a directory? by what name?), so I want to place the unziped contents into a directory named like the original zip file (in my case these are zip files students submitted to our Learning Management system).

I originally found the reverse of this, but it wasn't what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*.zip' -print -exec unzip '{}' -d '{}'-unzipped \;
```